# Jagged path created by planner

Tags: navigation, ros2, simulation, ros-humble, nav2

**Edit 3**: I consistently notice that when setting the value of `w_smooth` to 4 or more the planner server crashes (see **Edit 2** on bottom of page).

I have a question regarding the planner (NAV2): I am giving a navigation goal to my robot. The planner creates a path and the robot starts following it. The path changes frequently (in part because the obstacles found by the LIDAR are added in the costmaps). Some of those path changes are jagged paths.

[image: jagged paths]

[image: zoomed]

The code I used for my planner is:

```
planner_server:
  ros__parameters:
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]
    use_sim_time: True
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0          #Expected planner frequency. If the current frequency is less than the expected frequency, display the warning message.
    action_server_result_timeout: 10.0        # The timeout value (in seconds) for action servers to discard a goal handle if a result has not been produced. This used to default to 15 minutes in rcl but was changed to 10 seconds in this PR #1012, which may be less than some actions in Nav2 take to run. 
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_smac_planner/SmacPlannerHybrid"
      downsample_costmap: False                  # whether or not to downsample the map
      downsampling_factor: 2                    # multiplier for the resolution of the costmap layer (e.g. 2 on a 5cm costmap would be 10cm)
      tolerance: 0.4                           # tolerance for planning if unable to reach exact pose, in meters. Dist-to-goal heuristic cost (distance) for valid tolerance endpoints if exact goal cannot be found that would be acceptable to diverge from the requested pose.
      allow_unknown: True                      # allow traveling in unknown space
      max_iterations: 9000000                   # maximum total iterations to search for before failing (in case unreachable), set to -1 to disable
      max_on_approach_iterations: 1000          # Maximum number of iterations after within tolerances to continue to try to find exact solution
      max_planning_time: 15.0                    # max time in s for planner to plan, smooth
      motion_model_for_search: "REEDS_SHEPP"    #"REEDS_SHEPP" or "DUBIN" # Hybrid-A* Dubin, Redds-Shepp
      angle_quantization_bins: 72               # Number of angle bins for search
      
      # angle_quantization_bins is a parameter in many localization algorithms that 
      # controls how finely the algorithm discretizes the search space for possible 
      # orientations. A higher value for angle_quantization_bins means that the 
      # algorithm will consider more possible orientations, but will also be slower.
      #  A lower value for angle_quantization_bins means that the algorithm will be 
      #  faster, but may be less accurate. The default value for 
      #  angle_quantization_bins is 72, which corresponds to 5 degree increments.
      
      analytic_expansion_ratio: 3.5             # The ratio to attempt analytic expansions during search for final approach.
      analytic_expansion_max_length: 3.0        # For Hybrid/Lattice nodes: The maximum length of the analytic expansion to be considered valid to prevent unsafe shortcutting
      minimum_turning_radius: 0.6           # minimum turning radius in m of path / vehicle
      # Minumum turning radius calculated using simulations to around 0.6 meters
      # Penatlies
      reverse_penalty: 2.0                     # Penalty to apply if motion is reversing, must be => 1
      change_penalty: 0.1                       # Penalty to apply if motion is changing directions (L to R), must be >= 0
      non_straight_penalty: 2.0                # Penalty to apply if motion is non-straight, must be => 1
      cost_penalty: 9.5                         # Penalty to apply to higher cost areas when adding into the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic. This drives the robot more towards the center of passages. A value between 1.3 - 3.5 is reasonable.
      retrospective_penalty: 0.015              # Must be between 0.0 and 1.0 (0.0 is fully admissible)
      # reverse_penalty: This parameter controls how much the planner penalizes moving in the reverse direction. This is useful for avoiding situations where the robot has to back up, which can be slow and dangerous.
      # change_penalty: This parameter controls how much the planner penalizes changing direction. This is useful for avoiding situations where the robot has to make a lot of sharp turns, which can also be slow and dangerous.
      # non_straight_penalty: This parameter controls how much the planner penalizes moving in a non-straight direction. This is useful for encouraging the robot to move in straight lines whenever possible, which is more efficient.
      # cost_penalty: This parameter controls how much the planner penalizes moving to a pose with a high cost. This is useful for finding paths that are both safe and efficient.
      # retrospective_penalty: This parameter controls how much the planner penalizes moving to a pose that is earlier in the path. This is useful for encouraging the robot to find paths that are shorter and less complex

      lookup_table_size: 20.0                   # Size of the dubin/reeds-sheep distance window to cache, in meters.
      cache_obstacle_heuristic: true           # Cache the obstacle map dynamic programming distance expansion heuristic between subsiquent replannings of the same goal location. Dramatically speeds up replanning performance (40x) if costmap is largely static.
      smooth_path: false                         # If true, does a simple and quick smoothing post-processing to the path

      smoother:
        max_iterations: 1000
        w_smooth: 1.3
        w_data: 0.2
        tolerance: 1.0e-10
        do_refinement: true
        refinement_num: 2
```

Setting `smooth_path:` to `true` and varying the `w_smooth:`  parameter doesn't seem to help.

**Edit**: Apparently the `w_smooth` parameter indeed affects  heavily the path. Counterintuitively, by setting that parameter to e.g., 1.3, the planner will create really weird paths for a few split seconds such as in the figure below: (path is the green line)

[image: large w_smooth]

**Edit 2**: By setting the value to 4, the planner server dies:

```
[ERROR] [planner_server-4]: process has died [pid 92102, exit code -11, ... 
[lifecycle_manager-12] [INFO] [1696947017.752258363] [lifecycle_manager_navigation]: Have not received a heartbeat from planner_server.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your outrageous cost penalty is making it more viable to stop, reverse a little, then continue on rather than enter the costed space. That's a formal reversal. Try using more realistic parameters using the configuration guide's parameters as a starting point.

9.5 means you weight a high cost space 9.5x more than you weigh the same motion in freespace. That makes even really small incursions into any costed space super highly penalized to a degree that it will try to do almost anything not the enter any costed space, even if completely safe.

Or optionally you could change the motion model to Dubins so you don't reverse at all so that you don't run into that. Or I suppose jack up the reverse cost penalty as well to penalize reversing just as much as costed space.

Comment: Steven, thank you for your input. Decreasing the `cost_penalty` to a reasonable value (e.g., 2.5) does not solve the issue. Decreasing the value of `w_smooth` however seems to do the trick (regardless of the `cost_penalty` value). Seems counterintuitive that with a smaller value of `w_smooth` I get a less jagged path.

Comment: Again, this is not jagged. this is a formal reversal request due to your bad parameters. There is no jaggedness that can be made in Smac Planners since they are guaranteed feasible. Those are reversals since you're enabling the reeds-shepp model

Comment: Understandable, it is a purposefully selected reversal. Based on your expertise what parameters would you say are badly defined in my code and how does it makes sense that by decreasing the `w_smooth` value the reversals are gone?

Comment: No, messing with the smoother parameters makes no sense at all to resolve this problem